# Azure cloudapp.net domain and duplicate content issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a C#/MVC4 site hosted on Azure as a web role located at http://www.equispot.com. During a check on Google for some searches related to my site, I came across a search result that links to this page:

http://equispot.cloudapp.net/horses-for-sale/quarter-horses/13

*Note the difference in the domain name.* Now, I have a canonical tag already (view the source on the cloudapp.net link and you can see the canonical rel tag points to the main site at http://www.equispot.com).

Since that's the case, why would Google have indexed the page at the cloudapp.net domain? I recently noticed a drop in my SERPs and I'm wondering if this is part of the reason (I migrated to Azure about the same time as the SERP change). It may be unrelated but still...

How can I prevent these pages from being indexed by Google or how can I prevent my Azure web role from responding to anything except www.equispot.com and equispot.com? When I had this hosted on premise, I just configured IIS to respond only to my domain (my previous provider produced some dupe content for some reason as well).

Comment: weird... I have also have a MVC app BUT on azure websites and google indexes my urls just fine... we have no special configuration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a straightforward way to do this using hostHeader configuration in the ServiceDefinition.csdef file so I rolled my own `RedirectInvalidDomainsAttribute` class to perform a 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect back to my main site during a request for an invalid domain. In case anyone else runs into the same problem, here's the code:

**App_Start/FilterConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new RedirectInvalidDomainsAttribute());
}
```

**RedirectInvalidDomainsAttribute.cs**

```
public class RedirectInvalidDomainsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
        if (url == null) return;

        var host = url.Host;

        if (host.Contains("equispot.com") || host.Contains("localhost")) return;
        string subdomain = GetSubDomain(host);

        Guid guid;
        if (Guid.TryParseExact(subdomain, "N", out guid)) 
        {
            // this is a staging domain, it's okay
            return;
        }

        // Invalid domain - 301 redirect
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(url) {Host = "www.equispot.com"};
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(builder.Uri.ToString(), true);

    }

    // This isn't perfect, but it works for the sub-domains Azure provides
    private static string GetSubDomain(string host)
    {
        if (host.Split('.').Length > 1)
        {
            int index = host.IndexOf(".");
            return host.Substring(0, index);
        }

         return null;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check to make sure that the host the application is running under is the domain name you want. If it is not, then simply do a 302 redirect to the domain name you want.

There are several places where you can inspect the request and do the redirect:

```
 - Global.asax
 - Custom module
 - Override the OnActionExecuting for action methods
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of that but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it. Looking into hostHeader configuration in the ServiceDefinition.csdef file.